# Condense Dataframe by adding more columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to reformat my dataframe to a simplified example below:

Original DF:

```
ColA    ColB   ColC
week1     cat     10
week1     dog      8
week2     cat      2
week2     dog     28
week3     cat     12
week3     dog      7
```

Desired DF:

```
NewCol1     CatVal    DogVal
 week1       10         8
 week2        2         28
 week3       12         7
```

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `df.pivot(*df)` or `df.pivot(*df).add_suffix("Val").reset_index()` should do, for more intricate operations, please read the linked duplicate link